# Query time slows from 7 seconds to 40 seconds on adding a mediocre join, am I missing something?

Tags: mysql, join, optimization

Advance apologies if this question is dumb.

So I have a large table with results of a survey:

Table Survey (120million rows):
    Points (tinyint(1))
    Question (varchar(13))
    CityID (smallint(3)) Index
    PersonID (varchar(13))
    Autoincrement (int(7)) PK

Then I have a much smaller lookup table:

Table city_lookup (<1000 rows)
    CityID (smallint(3)) PK
    City (varchar(13))

If I do:

```
select sum(Points), CityID
from Survey
where CityID = 256
group by CityID
```

The query returns 1 row, and takes 7 seconds

But if I do:

```
select sum(Points), City
from Survey
inner join city_lookup on Survey.CityID = city_lookup.CityID
where Survey.CityID = 256
group by City
```

Then the query, still returning 1 row, takes 40 seconds.

I know that if I adjust the query such that the join only happens after the aggregated query has run, i.e. put main query in a subquery, then it'll bring it down to 7 seconds... but should I have to do this, or am I missing some obvious step of optimisation?

Comment: I know 7 seconds is slow but there's 120million rows. I'm just unsure if I'm missing something on why the join makes it so much slower.

Comment: Ahh, I just saw that as well, never mind then!

Comment: bit of a late reply, but I found that if I did a left join, it took only the same length of time as no join at all... I don't know if it's something to do with an inner join strictly filtering on a join before it combines the joined data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DBMS probably joins 120 million rows before aggregating. I suggest you aggregate first and join then:

```
select c.city, s.sum_points
from city_lookup c
join
(
  select sum(Points) as sum_points, CityID
  from Survey
  where CityID = 256
  group by CityID
) s on s.cityid = c.cityid;
```

I'd create the following index for this:

```
CREATE idx ON survey(cityid, points);
```

Answer (score 2):

Knowing nothing else about your DB setup, if this is fast:

```
select sum(Points), CityID
from Survey
where CityID = 256
group by CityID
```

then this should be fast as well:

```
select
  s.CityID, s.SumPoints, c.City
from 
  (
    select sum(Points) SumPoints, CityID
    from Survey
    where CityID = 256
    group by CityID
  ) s
  inner join city_lookup c ON c.CityID = s.CityID
```